# Where to get proofs of open problems checked?

Tags: correctness-proof

I have found what I believe is a proof of related to an open problem in computer science.  I've written it up in LaTeX, and I am looking for a way to get it evaluated.  I know that cs.se/cstheory.se are not the appropriate forums to post this proof; what is the appropriate place to share my proof?

Comment: That is what journals, conferences, and such are for. Find some way to put it before knowledgeable eyes. Perhaps summarize it here...

Comment: Here's a link to the paper:  https://philip-white-website.000webhostapp.com/proof.pdf

Comment: A three-page proof of independence of P=NP from ZFC is extremely unlikely to be correct. I'm not a set theorist, so I can't give more specific advice. I would suggest removing all claims that things are clear, can be proved in a similar way to something else, etc., and replace them with explicit proofs. That may reveal errors. Beyond that, [this thread on Academia SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/18491/10685) is a good place to start.